# Mavericks: Preview pane spontaneously reappears when switching spaces

Tags: macos, spaces, fullscreen

Sometime my preview pane spontaneously reappears whenever I switch to another (non full-screen) Space, e.g., with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> . This behavior continues even after I close the preview pane. Sometimes it continues even when I have closed all Finder windows. Moreover, when this is occurring, I cannot reach Spaces with full-screen applications open. It seems to happen when I am switching spaces with the preview pane open in the first place.

How can I change this behavior? What is causing it?

Set-up: Mac Mini, Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to fix this properly, but killing the Dock (forcing it to auto-restart) stops the quicklook pane reappearing. Just run this from a Terminal window:

```
killall Dock
```